# TableNotFoundException: hbase:labels

Tags: csv, hbase, bulk-load

I'm trying to upload tsv file to HBase using this command

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,info:email,info:country,info:continent test_table /user/test/1row.tsv
```

My table defined as

```
create 'test_table',{NAME=>'info',REPLICATION_SCOPE=>'1'}
```

In MapReduce log appears error

```
2015-12-07 09:07:20,576 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.DefaultVisibilityExpressionResolver: Error scanning 'labels' table
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: hbase:labels
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1298)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1126)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:299)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:149)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:57)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:293)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:268)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:140)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:135)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:888)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.DefaultVisibilityExpressionResolver.init(DefaultVisibilityExpressionResolver.java:90)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CellCreator.<init>(CellCreator.java:48)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TsvImporterMapper.setup(TsvImporterMapper.java:107)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I am using Cloudera Express 5.4.7 distribution and HBase 1.0.0-cdh5.4.8 version.

Actually I am looking for workaround because I am not interested in Visibility feature of HBase usage at all.

Also I can't install any HBase patch in my working cluster.

thanks in advance!

Comment: did you get the workaround? I am also getting the same error. Can you please share how you proceeded?

Comment: it was more that one year ago and I really do not remember my workaround, sorry. If I will meet this problem today I will create Hive table on top of csv file, then create another Hive table with org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler and then run insert as select Hive command.

Comment: it seems that this is still an [unresolved bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14365) !!!

Comment: Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when using HBase locally for development. A quick workaround (to get importTSV to not fail) is to simply create the table in question as such:

`create 'hbase:labels', 'f'`